# Mac Upload and Download Speeds

Tags: catalina, mojave, big-sur, monterey

I am trying to find the difference between Mac computers and Windows 10 & 11 computer upload and download speeds. I need the updload and down load speeds for the following operating systems for Mac Monterey, Mac Big Sur, Mac Catalina, and Mac Mojave.

Comment: Up and download speeds are basically completely independent from the OS and only depend on the specs of machine and connection. Is there an actual problem you are trying to solve? I can assure you: If you take the same computer components and the same connection, the Mac and the Windows machine will the same up and download performance.

Comment: @x_841 That‘s not entirely correct. The implementation of the network stack is different, this probably has an effect on speed.

Comment: thats why I said *basically*. Of course, OS and even OS versions behave differently since they don't consist of the same code, yet, any modern OS will behave so similar in most user tasks, I highly doubt that there will be any noticable difference. All other factors will have much more impact.

Answer (score 3):

Download speeds are largely dependent on the hardware, e.g. the rating for the Wifi or Ethernet controller; and in the case of Wifi, the quality of the over-the-air connection.

Upload speeds are largely controlled by the ISP providing the line.

A quick Google will show you some people having faster speeds, and some having slower, when using Windows in BootCamp, compared to MacOS on the same hardware.

There are of course all sorts of other 'real world' factors.

The  concept of 'a download speed' for a given OS is therefore not really something that can be measured.